# eliminate render blocking resource in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, pagespeed-insights

how to eliminate render blocking resource, please give some solution.

and in below URL
**https://example.com/media/css_secure/A.67235d48adca9db7ca959bc3a5076d7a.css.pagespeed.cf.Zdz540Fens.css**

what is that **pagespeed.cf.Zdz540Fens.css** extension in above URL and how to remove that file.[image]

Comment: That doesn't sound like a core file, if it is not a core file then it entirely depends on how it's added in your project. If you search your codebase for 'pagespeed' what is returned?

Comment: he wont find that in code, the pagespeed css and js files are being generated by an apache or nginx pagespeed module. What version of pagespeed are you using?

Comment: @paj i dont know the version of pagespeed